# How to use select event in ngx-tree-select (Angular)

Tags: angular

I'm using `ngx-tree-select` component in my angular project.

I have a question about select event. I'm trying to trigger a function on item selection, but it doesn't work.

The only event that works is `onModelChange`, but it is not suitable for my case.

Maybe i'm doing something wrong? Help me please.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form class="form-control">
                <tree-select name="simpleSelect"
                             [items]="items | async"
                             idField="id"
                             textField="name"
                             childrenField="children"
                             [(ngModel)]="selected"
                             [allowFilter]="false"
                             [multiple]="false"
                             required=true
                             [allowParentSelection]="true"
                             (select)="select()">
                </tree-select>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Component code:

```
select(): void {
  console.log('test')
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us some code?

Comment: Updated my question. Thanks

Comment: seems the component your are using haven't this output event. If you can link the docs of the library, we can check this.

Comment: On the github page of this component i did not find any information about this. Here is the  [link](https://github.com/Crazyht/ngx-tree-select)

Answer (score 0):

```
private _simpleSelected: "any obj";

     get simpleSelected() : any obj {
      return this._simpleSelected;
      }

     set simpleSelected(value: any obj) {
      this._simpleSelected = value;
      }
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users is you included some context to explain how your answer helps.